# Initial window split in termdebug vim

Tags: vim, gdb, vim-plugin

I am new to vim and recently came to know that we can use Termdebug to debug code in vim with gdb. I liked this very much as i was searching for a good vim integration with gdb. 
When i launch Termdebug window is split horizontally in gdb window, program window & source code window. I like to vertically split source code window to right. For that, currently i move focus on source code window and press Ctrl+w & L.

**Before splitting:**

[image]

**After splitting:**

[image]

This i have to do every time i launch Termdebug. Is there a way to .vimrc so that when i launch Termdebug, source code window is automatically splitted to right. I have seen here which suggests to use:

```
let g:termdebug_wide = 163
```

This does automatic splitting but it has some problem in highlighting lines during debug as can be seen in picture below:

[image]

Please suggest how can i change .vimrc

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This layout—with the editor on the right, and both GDB windows split horizontally on the left—can be set by configuring `g:termdebug_wide` in your `.vimrc`.

```
let g:termdebug_wide=1
```

See `:help termdebug_wide` for details.

I wrote a blog post on `termdebug` last year (May 2019), and recently (April 2020) addressed this same issue in a comment:
https://www.dannyadam.com/blog/2019/05/debugging-in-vim/#comment-251004

Answer (score 6):

Finally, I found how to do this by modifying vimrc. I mapped the whole sequence of keys to F6 for convenience.

```
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F6> :Termdebug %:r<CR><c-w>2j<c-w>L
```

I added the above line in vimrc. Now, when i press F6 automatically opens windows with source code window on right like in the question above with no strange behavior.

**Explanation**:

- `:Termdebug %:r<CR>`  This will open Termdebug with all 3 windows horizontally.
- `<c-w>2j` This will move focus to the source code window.
- `<c-w>L` This will move source code window to the right.

**Note**: If you want focus back on the gdb window, you can add `<c-w>h` at the end of the above line.